# Two Subqueries in Select part of SQL query

Tags: sql

I have been asked to create two new columns in a sql statement I have the basic Statements down but whenever I try to put them together in a statement I get a error I have tried making them part of a UNION statement but still get the error. Any tips on what I am doing wrong SQL Statements below

```
    select 
wdate, 
sum(pl_meter1) as plan_1b,
sum(re_meter1) as result_1b, 
sum(pl_meter2) as plan_2b, 
sum(re_meter2) as result_2b, 
(Select ITDSC1 FROM AGGW.gwd1110 where  SUBSTR(ITDSC1,18,1) = 'G') AS PLANG,
 (Select ITDSC1 FROM AGGW.gwd1110 where SUBSTR(ITDSC1,18,1) != 'G') AS PLANNG  
from   aggw.gwd1110  
where   wdate >= 20160529 
group by wdate 
order by wdate;
```

Comment: What is your desired output? and Input/sample data? you can probably do this in a single group by with no subselects

Comment: Are you getting an error where the subquery is returning more than one value?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos has a point that your SUBSELECT probably needs to be in an agreggate function but is ITDSC1 even a numeric field?  Post data and describe the result you want please.

Comment: It isn't a numeric field it is a string field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
select wdate, 
       sum(pl_meter1) as plan_1b,
       sum(re_meter1) as result_1b, 
       sum(pl_meter2) as plan_2b, 
       sum(re_meter2) as result_2b, 
       max(case when SUBSTR(ITDSC1,18,1) = 'G' then ITDSC1 end) AS PLANG,
       max(case when SUBSTR(ITDSC1,18,1) != 'G' then ITDSC1 end) AS PLANNG  
from aggw.gwd1110  
where wdate >= 20160529 
group by wdate 
order by wdate;
```

Comment: @Demilich1988 Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.